# How to implement a callback when auth state changes in supabase

Tags: javascript, supabase

I'm struggling to implement an idea. If a user is logged in, I want to show a hidden div.

For example in firebase I can do this:

```
firebase.auth.signInAnonymessly()

// Detecting if the auth state changed
firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  // If a user exists show him a hidden div
  if(user) {
    HiddenDiv.style.display = block
  }
})
```

I want to do this but in supabase

I searched the supabase docs and didn't find anything pls help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a method in Supabase that works in almost the same way as Firebases' `onAuthStateChange`, here's a reference to the [docs](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-onauthstatechange).

```js
supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) => {
  console.log(event, session)
})
```